# CSS Grid auto-fit + minmax adds phantom row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

There seems to be a strange bug in CSS grid for Chrome (doesn't happen in Firefox). It happens when using repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr)) for the grid-template-columns style. For some reason even though there are only two child divs, the parent div thinks there is a another element and generates a huge amount of whitespace and unnecessary grid gaps. Any idea how to legitimately fix this without making a janky fix?

Here's a recreation of the bug: 
https://codepen.io/rantis/full/gXxxRB/

```
.two_item_grid_container {
  repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  /* If you reduce the min size to 45px the grid fixes itself for some reason */
}
```

[image: Layout with Chrome's new visual grid lines]

[image: The HTML of the parent plus children]

[image: The CSS of the parent with the grid]

Comment: You should post enough code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B see the edits above. There's a link to a codepen demo I made which shows the issue.

Comment: @PorcupineRending questions about debugging code need to include the code *in the question itself*; a link to an off-site demo is inadequate.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47704097/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B I ended up reporting the bug to the Chrome development team and they confirmed it was an bug but was already fixed for Chrome v63 and above;  so when that publicly rolls out it will be less of an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does appear to be a rendering difference between Chrome and Firefox / Edge when using `auto-fill` in this context. Here is a possible workaround:

**Use a more definite column size and a media query.**

```
.two_item_grid_container {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(300px, 1fr));
     grid-auto-rows: auto;
     grid-gap: 20px;
}

@media ( max-width: 500px ) {
  .two_item_grid_container {
     grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYLKoQ)

Comment: Thanks Michael! This seems like a bug on Chrome's end of things. Can you tell what's actually happening?

Comment: Chrome appears to be creating tracks for prospective occupancy. Not sure why. So when your second item wraps, Chrome already has the space reserved. Firefox and Edge appear to be more sensible in this case.

Comment: There may be a natural workaround, but I don't know what it may be. I tested `auto-fill` and flexbox, but neither made things easier. So I went with the media query hammer.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I was hoping to avoid a work around but I suppose I need to set up media queries anyway. Thank you for your help!